# Unable to scroll by pixels

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, scrollbar

I have a panel that shows a 2D array of cells. Each cell is 32x32 pixels in a 100x100 cell grid. My panel is only big enough to display 45x30 cells. When I use the scrollbar, it updates the display moving cell by cell. The desired effect I'm looking for is to move the horizontally or vertically by pixel, which would have a greater precision of movement. The end result would be if I clicked a scrollbar's arrow button, instead of updating cell by cell, the panel will update pixel row/column by row/column. In other words, I'm trying to get smooth scrolling (1 pixel row/column at a time) insteand of jerky scrolling (1 cell/32 pixels at a time).

Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved?

Comment: Did you check **Panel.HorizontalScroll.SmallChange** and Panel.VerticalScroll.SmallChange properties?

Comment: what's the type of your `cell`?

Comment: @KingKing the cells are placeholders for an images (int)

Comment: @SpicyWeenie but what is the control displaying the image? a `PictureBox`?

Comment: @KingKing Im using a Panel to display the grid of images

Comment: Window scrolling behavior is determined by system settings, nothing you can do about it in your own program.  You didn't mention a Windows version so hard to help you.  Ask a question about it at superuser.com